# Pass and automatically update data between views?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

On my website I have two sections/columns, left and right. Both have their own html partial and controller.

In my left column I have a partial that display a list of lists.

When I click a list in the left column, I want the elements in this list to be displayed in the right column (different controller and view). So, I need to pass the list from "left" controller to "right" controller and automatically update the "right" view.

What would be the best Angular practice to achieve this? Should I use custom directives maybe?

Comment: @LVarayut Noope , that wont :P
every controller owns his scope, if you want to share something between them , there are some great ways , but not your way

Comment: for exmaple . the dummy one is to use $routeScope
if you bind anything to $routeScope , all controllers will get the update from routeScope

Comment: Is the right controller a child of the left controller? That would help, because the scope of the right controller would then inherit from the scope of the left controller. In short: Show us some code.

Comment: Right now the controllers are siblings. My code isn't really relevant because its more a question of general architecture.

Comment: I would make them parent/child. The detail (right) is used to display what it selected in the list (left), so it makes sense. Then just initialize an attribute "selectedList" in the left scope, and the right scope will inherit it.

Comment: I did not know scope inheritance worked like that. Seems like a good practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just use a service.

```
app.service('dataService', function() {
  return{
    'data': "Hello"  
  };
});
```

Now inject `dataService` in each controller and access the data from there by calling `dataService.data`.